# Are Ember.js-based web apps CSP-Compliant?

Tags: javascript, security, google-chrome, ember.js, google-chrome-app

Google Chrome’s Packaged Apps need to [comply with CSP](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html). Assuming you compile your Handlebars templates before deployment, does that apply to Ember.js?

For some reason, Google [doesn’t list Ember.js as a recommended MVC framework](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_frameworks.html#recommended).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the time of writing the docs, Ember wasn't CSP compliant due to use of `eval` or `new Function` in the code - which was mainly around the Handlebars templating side of things.

With the correct build tools, Ember templates can be precompiled. The [grunt-ember-templates](https://github.com/dgeb/grunt-ember-templates) npm package will handle this for you. This package is used by [ember-app-kit](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-app-kit) which is becoming the default recommended Ember build tools. If you like Rails you can use [ember-appkit-rails](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-appkit-rails) instead.

If for some reason you want to use uncompiled templates, you can of course use the [sandbox attribute](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external.html#sandboxing) to isolate your page from the Chrome apps API's and allow use of eval.

Comment: @PeterWagenet I have made this a community wiki answer if you would like to update it.

Answer (score 2):

ember applications created with ember-cli are CSP compliant since version [0.0.47](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/2065). hope google reevaluate their recommendations.